# How to get client host name in .net core api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, .net-core

I have created an angular front-end and the .net core c# API. The client application(angular) hosted in two separate domain names like abc.com and xyz.com. I need to know how do I get the where the request come from to the api.

Example:

- If request come from abc.com I need to identify the request come from abc.com
- If request come from xyz.com I need to identify the request come from xyz.com

  **I need to know how I get the client app hosted domain name from the request in .net core. Not the client's IP address. Need to get hosted domain name of the client app.**

Comment: Where do you need this info? On the server side, or the client side?

Comment: if you need this on the server side you can pass the it as header, from server side you can get the client's ip address `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Referrer URI.

Referrer URI is the URI of application which has initiated the request to your application.

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
Response.Write("Referrer URL Port: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Port.ToString()) + "<br>");
Response.Write("Referrer URL Protocol: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Scheme) + "<br>");
```

Refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?view=netframework-4.8) for further details.